# Can I paste image data with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, clipboard

There are scripts like http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/ to copy text data, not sure about binary data. What I want to know is if theres a way to paste image data with JS? I want to paste image data that will be uploaded to Imgur for example